# Not filling out non-mandatory fields in HR forms

Tags: human-resources

Was given HR forms to fill out before my first day, it included non-mandatory fields such as including your various social media (which I'm not filling out) and education.

Would I be shooting myself in the foot by not bothering to fill out a non-mandatory field like my education (school, gpa, degree, etc) they can fish it out of my resume from when I applied. I suppose I may be paranoid of giving HR any more information about me, or making it easily accessible seeing the old adage about HR is not your friend.

Comment: it's... not an "old adage". they're just another department in a company. You might as well say "Tech is not your friend" or "Sales is not your friend" or "Security is not your friend". You still have to work with them, you all share a common goal (the success of whichever firm), why make their lives harder?

Answer (score 8):

> the old adage about HR is not your friend.

They also aren't your enemy (unless you've done something wrong that could hurt the company), so don't treat them like one.

Protecting your privacy by not sharing social media is fine, but withholding reasonable information that could be found on line, just because you don't trust them, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Since they already have this information that was on your resume you really aren't giving them any *more* information then they already have.

Anything listed as non-mandatory that isn't readily available on materials you've already submitted is of course totally optional (I can see why you may not wish to submit social media info for example)

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that HR is not your friend, but you're *approaching this in the wrong way*.

A friend might not mind if you neglected to give them information that they already had elsewhere, unbothered that they need to retrieve that information themselves. Someone who is not your friend would be more annoyed by your apparent unwillingness or inability to follow simple instructions.

So yes, HR is not your friend, so you should want to *keep them happy* by making their job as easy as possible.

For personal information not related to the job duties such as social media, obviously there is no harm in omitting this information.

Comment: At the very minimum, you don't want them to notice you for a negative reason.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't started working for them but yet you want to take shortcuts...

I can totally understand why you would be reluctant to provide too much information that is not actually relevant to the job as your social media accounts.
On the other hand, I think that filling in the gaps for info they already have is something you could do just out of courtesy for the people that will have to deal with this paper. OK the company might have that info already somewhere, but you don't know if it is easily accessible for the people dealing with that form, how long it would take them to copy/paste information from there, the mistakes they could make, etc... If you can spare them these complications just by spending a few extra minutes filling it yourself, why not ? HR may not be your friend, but you need to go through them to get hired anyway.